# 2 of my read/write close calls "cannot find symbol" in java. I cant understand why

Tags: java

The program reads from a data file, pulls out `substrings` and places them into a string `array`.  The reader is closed. The data is then reduced and written to an output file. Then the writer is closed. In both of those cases, `br.close` and `writer.close`, the compiler returns **cannot find symbo** referring to the `br` and writer variables. Noted that the `scan.close()` compiles. i don't understand what is wrong here.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;
import java.text.NumberFormat;

public class Module10A_Revision1{

   public static void main ( String[] args )throws FileNotFoundException{


   String dataPoint;
   String[][] data;
   String[][] compressedData = new String[56][5];
   int totalDataPoints = 0;
   int count = 0;

   int state = 0;
   int total = 0;
   int children = 0;
   int poverty = 0;
   int tempState    = 0;
   int tempTotal      = 0;
   int tempChildren = 0;
   int tempPoverty  = 0;

//MEASURE SIZE FOR ARRAY

      File file = new File("data.txt");
      Scanner scan = new Scanner(file);

      //Determine the total number of items listed in the file

      while (scan.hasNextLine()){

         scan.nextLine();
         totalDataPoints++;
      }
      scan.close(); (COMPILER HAS NO ISSUES WITH THIS ONE. BUT 2 BELOW FAIL.)

      data = new String[totalDataPoints][6];

//READ

      try{

         FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("data.txt");
         BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fstream)); 


         //equate a substring to a temp variable
         while ((dataPoint = br.readLine()) != null){

            String stateCode = dataPoint.substring(1,2);
            String districtID = dataPoint.substring(4,8);
            String districtName = dataPoint.substring(10,81);
            String totalPop = dataPoint.substring(83,90);
            String childrenPop = dataPoint.substring(92,99);
            String povertyPop = dataPoint.substring(101,108);

            //read into array         

            data[count][0] = stateCode;
            data[count][1] = districtID;
            data[count][2] = districtName;
            data[count][3] = totalPop;
            data[count][4] = childrenPop;
            data[count][5] = povertyPop;

            count++;
         }//end while 

      }//end try
      catch (Exception e){
         e.printStackTrace();
      }//end catch
      br.close();
```

(`br` is one of the two variables the compiler cannot find)

```
//PROCESS DATA

      for (int j = 0; j < 56; j++){

      state = 0;
      total = 0;
      children = 0;
      poverty = 0;      

         for (int i = 0; i < totalDataPoints; i++){

            tempState    = Integer.parseInt(data[i][0]);
            tempTotal    = Integer.parseInt(data[i][3]);
            tempChildren = Integer.parseInt(data[i][4]);
            tempPoverty  = Integer.parseInt(data[i][5]);

            if (i == tempState){

               total = total + tempTotal;
               children = children + tempChildren;
               poverty = poverty + tempPoverty;

            }
            else{
               break;
            } // end if

         }//end for j

         NumberFormat defaultFormat = NumberFormat.getPercentInstance();
          defaultFormat.setMinimumFractionDigits(2);
         double perCent = 100*poverty/children;
         //perCent = defaultFormat.format(perCent);

         compressedData[j][0] = Integer.toString(tempState);
         compressedData[j][1] = Integer.toString(total);
         compressedData[j][2] = Integer.toString(children);
         compressedData[j][3] = Integer.toString(poverty);
         compressedData[j][4] = Double.toString(perCent);

      }//end for i


      //create buffer for writing string
      //BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("compressedData.txt"));

//WRITE

      try{

         FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("compressedData.txt");  

         // Loop over the elements in the string array and write each line.
         for(int i = 0; i < 56; i++){

            for(int j = 0; j < 5; j++){

               writer.append(compressedData[i][j]);

               if(j < compressedData[j].length - 1)  
                  writer.append(',');  
               else 
                  writer.append('\n');

            }// end j

         }//end i

      }//end try
      catch(IOException e){  

         e.printStackTrace();  

      } //end catch
      finally{

         writer.close(); ( writer IS THE OTHER VARIABLE THE COMPILER CANNOT FIND)

      }//end finally

   }//end main

}//end class
```

Comment: Please dont SHOUT.

Answer (score 0):

> THE COMPILER RETURNS "CANNOT FIND SYMBOL" REFERRING TO THE br AND
>   writer VARIABLES.

The problem is that you declared the `br` inside the `try` block, but use it outside `try-catch` block.

You should declare `br` as global or declare in the main method

`BufferedReader br ;`

Then only `br= new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fstream));`

Comment: Duh. Thank you. Another pair of eyes always does the trick...

Comment: please mark my answer...thanks